# Storing everything with JSON.stringify on localstorage

Tags: javascript, typescript, local-storage

I am trying to do a localStorage helper and occurred to me to just stringify everything when setting to localstorage, then parse when getting, so I have the following helper functions:

```
  get<T = string>(key: string): T {
    const item = localStorage.getItem(key);
    return JSON.parse(item) as T;
  }

  set<T = string>(key: string, item: T) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item));
  }
```

The pros I thought were that I don't need to create separate functions for `getString` and `getObject`, or treat the exception if `JSON.parse` fails, or check the string characters to see if it's a object, list, bool, etc.

My problem is that it seems like a bad practice. Is it? If so, why?

Comment: The main Issue is that JSON parsing/stringifying can take a toll on performance for large objects, in data-intensive environments WebSQL and IndexedDB perform better since they do not block the JS event loop. you can also look at localForage does this (as they use JSON.stringify + their own format for TypedArrays)

Comment: It's a perfectly common practice.